# How to write a constraint that references the Objective in R optimization

Tags: r, optimization, solver, infrastructure, r-optimization

Here is the objective I would like to maximize in R:

> AX1+BX2+CX3+DX4

The following constraints exists

> 0 >= S2 >= 8
>
> 0 >= S3 >= 8
>
> 0 >= S4 >= 8
>
> 0 >= S5 >= 8

Where

> S2 = X1 + V
>
> S3 = X2 + X1 + V
>
> S4 = X3 + X2 + X1 + V
>
> S5 = X4 + X3 + X2 + X1 + V

Basically, the constraints reference the objective.

As an example, if V = 4, X1 = 2, then S2 = 6. (therefore the constraint, 0 >= S2 >=  is not violated.

How do I reference the objective (I used L_Objective function) in the constraint function?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How do the constraints reference the objective function? Also what is V?

Comment: Hi Noah, I made some edits and added some examples.  Does that help?

Comment: I still don't see how this differs from a regular optimization problem. Just replace the Ss with the values you set for them and this is totally standard linear programming optimization problem with linear inequality constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I'll try it and follow up.  

My apologies for the confusion.  There is a constraint for X4 and I added it.

I tried to simplify the premise to focus on my exact problem but I think it might have left out key details.

To give context, I am trying to optimize the charging and discharge of a battery over 24 hours.  There is a limit to the amount of charge the battery can hold, so it can't discharge once it reaches its minimum stored charge and can't charge once it reaches its maximum charge.

Comment: Only the last constraint (S5) matters. The others are automatically satisfied if S5 is satisfied.

Comment: But what is V? Nowhere have you defined V. Is it the objective function `V = AX1+BX2+CX3+DX4`, or is it some other scalar constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Does the following not work?

```
library(ROI)

obj <- L_objective(c(A, B, C, D)

const.mat <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0,
                      1, 1, 0, 0,
                      1, 1, 1, 0,
                      1, 1, 1, 1),
                    nrow = 4)
const <- L_constraint(rbind(const.mat, constmat),
                      dir = c(rep(">=", 4), rep("<=", 4)),
                      rhs = c(rep(0-V, 4),    rep(8-V, 4)))
op <- op(obj, const, maximum = TRUE)
out <- ROI_solve(op)
```

Of course, filling in the correct values for A, B, C, D, and V, which I assume you have. If the last constraint is satisfied, the others will be automatically, so it's the only one that matters.